# How to view the contents of a .pem certificate?

Tags: certificate, keytool, pem

I am using Java `keytool`. I have exported a self-signed `.pem` certificate from my keystore. Is there a command to view the certificate details directly from the `.pem` file (not of the certificate in the keystore)?

Comment: Portecle is also very useful for that: http://portecle.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Use the [`-printcert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_printcert) command like this:

```
keytool -printcert -file certificate.pem
```

Comment: I am getting the error java.lang.Exception: Failed to parse input

Comment: @Maximilian it may happen on APNS certificates, which combines private key & certificate into one `.pem`. Separate them into 2 files using text editor and the above command will work. (Hint: copy `-- BEGIN CERTIFICATE --` line to `-- END CERTIFICATE --` line to new file)

Comment: needs java (jdk or jre)

Comment: Check the name of your pem file.

Answer (score 543):

An alternative to using `keytool`, you can use the command

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -text
```

This should work for any x509 .pem file provided you have [`openssl`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-x509.html#Display-Options) installed.

Comment: Actually, `keytool` errored out with `java.lang.Exception: Failed to parse input` for some pems, but this worked for all of them

Comment: If you want the aliases only: `openssl x509 -in file.pem -text | grep -A 1 'Alternative Name'`

Comment: In my case I had to change "x509" with "rsa" so I guess it depends on the .pem contents. I used `file` command to know that it was "rsa" and not "x509" (e.g. `file xyz.pem`).

Comment: @megatux a PEM file can contain a few different types of data `x509` is the format for certificates, `rsa` is the format for a public/private key pair.

Comment: A rookie approach is to open the pem file using Firefox

Comment: For shorter text-output try: `openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -text -noout`  - This will omit the last  ~ 40 lines of text  from the output ( BEGIN CERTIFICATE ...  END CERTIFICATE stuff)

Comment: to get only the subject: `openssl x509 -noout -subject -in  file.pem`

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, no external tools needed, just powershell:

Import cert file to variable $cert

```
$fpath = "path-to-file"
$cert = New-Object Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2([string]$fpath)
```

To view all content of certificate, type

```
$cert | select *
```

Should work for other cert extensions as well.

Comment: Screenshot would be nice. Is it console or GUI output?

Comment: @PaulVerest Console output.

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell it is sufficient to go to the folder with the crt creticifate.
Type in the name of the certificate.
Hit enter. Next you will see a dialog box with details of the certificate/