# My admincerts got expired and how to renew them after expiry when all the nodes are giving bad certificate error?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

My admincerts got expired and how to renew them after expiry when all the nodes are giving bad certificate error ? I'm using hyperledger fabric 1.4 version and raft consensus ? Is possible to get out of this lockout situation ? I

```
2020-12-18 11:25:41.676 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 702 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=1**.***.***.3:47104
```

Answer (score 0):

First the logs do not say anything like expired cert.
I would recommend using OpenSSL to check the details of the certificate. More logs are beneficial for debugging.

[how to view the contents of a .pem certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758238/how-to-view-the-contents-of-a-pem-certificate)

Use Open SSL to renew self signed certificate. Make sure you have the private key.

[How to renew a self-signed openssl PEM certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620685/how-to-renew-a-self-signed-openssl-pem-certificate)

Next you would be required to restart the containers.
If you are running a dockerised version of HLF, make sure you have redundancy before you take down the