# How to check certificate chain with linux command line tool

Tags: ssl, certificate

I know you can inspect the certificate by:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -text
```

ref: [How to view the contents of a .pem certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758238/how-to-view-the-contents-of-a-pem-certificate)

But how do I know from the output of the above command that the certificate is trusted or not?

The problem is, when I try to connect to an HTTPS server using let's encrypt certificate, my client reports:

```
tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

The problem is solved, however, I would like to know a better way to find out which certificate on the chain is missing from the local machine.

Comment: I recommend that you use [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to check the HTTPS setup since this reports the information about which certificates are missing. Apart from that `openssl s_client -showcerts`  will show you what certificates are sent by the server, so you can check based on analyzing the output where it gets wrong. In addition you could use `openssl verify` to check the relations between the certificates . But this requires more expertise - SSLLabs is much easier to use.

Comment: *"But how do I know from the output of the above command that the certificate is trusted or not?"* - you can't. You have to check against all the intermediate certificates sent by the server. And ultimately trust depends on the trusted root CA - which can be different between applications and even browser profiles (if users decided to add/remove some CA).